# Prove $A \cup \bar A = \mathcal U$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How can I prove It? I'm not used to proves involving Universal set.
I know that sets are equality It they mutually subsets of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in\mathcal{U}$ then $x\in A$ or $x\not\in A$, so either way $x\in A\cup\bar{A}$; the converse is trivial.